# Python: Generalized Pyplot stacked bars

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, stacked

I have tried to generalize the example given on [matplotlib.org](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html) for a *stacked bar plot*.

```
labels = ('G1','G2','G3','G4','G5');
values = [(20,35,30,35,27),(25,32,34,20,25),(3,4,5,6,7)];

for i in range(len(values)):
    if i == 0:
        plt.bar(np.arange(len(labels)),values[i],1);
    else:
        plt.bar(np.arange(len(labels)),values[i],1,bottom=values[i-1]);

plt.xticks(np.arange(len(labels))+0.5,labels);
```

But now I get the problem, that the bars do not seem to stack properly:
[image]

If you want to run the code, `import numpy as np`, `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `plt.show()`.

If you like, you can also suggest how to get different colors for each bar.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle
from six.moves import zip

def stack_bar(ax, list_of_vals, color_cyle=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Generalized stacked bar graph.

    kwargs are passed through to the call to `bar`

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : matplotlib.axes.Axes
       The axes to plot to

    list_of_vals : iterable
       An iterable of values to plot

    color_cycle : iterable, optional
       color_cycle is None, defaults
       to `cycle(['r', 'g', 'b', 'k'])`


    """
    if color_cyle is None:
        color_cyle = cycle(['r', 'g', 'b', 'k'])
    else:
        color_cycle = cycle(color_cycle)


    v0 = len(list_of_vals[0])
    if any(v0 != len(v) for v in list_of_vals[1:]):
           raise ValueError("All inputs must be the same length")

    edges = np.arange(v0)
    bottom = np.zeros(v0)
    for v, c in zip(list_of_vals, color_cyle):
        ax.bar(edges, v, bottom=bottom, color=c, **kwargs)
        bottom += np.asarray(v)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
values = [(20,35,30,35,27),(25,32,34,20,25),(3,4,5,6,7)]
stack_bar(ax, values, width=1)
```

it needs some bells-and-whistles and error checking

also as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tacaswell/b1a35a27a7d73f7408d2)

Answer (score 1):

There was a misconception about the use of `bottom`. The working code is now:

```
for i in range(len(values)):
    plt.bar(np.arange(len(labels)),values[i],1,bottom=[sum([values[j][pos] for j in range(i)]) for pos in range(len(labels))]);
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(labels))+0.5,labels);
```

And for an easily printable distinction I will now use the color kwarg such:

```
color=str(1.0/(len(values)-i))
```